# Push to git during build

Tags: git, jenkins

Jenkins has a post-build Git Publisher that can push to Git when the build job is done. But I want to push to git and then do some other stuff during my job.

Is this possible? I find when I try to just run `git push` during the build that I don't have any credentials set (apparently Jenkins uses `GIT_SSH` to do the fetching and pushing, but that environment variable isn't actually set during the build).

How can I access that `GIT_SSH` environment variable during the build?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you're going to downvote. Is this question off-topic?

Comment: How are you checking out the code currently? Using the Git client?

Comment: @Arran Yup, standard Git client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by making a pipeline job with multiple stages. The first stage makes source modifications and then does a post-build push, then the second phase does the rest of the stuff I want.